# Why won't my JavaScript calculations involving if statements work?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The idea is to generate a random number from 1 to 10, which will be the amount of pounds of product ordered. Then, using that number, the code will calculate the cost of the product and the cost of the shipping, adding them together to create a total. It will then write information about the purchase to the HTML document.

The problem is not the random number generator; that's working fine. It also doesn't appear to be the final step of writing information to the document. Rather, it seems that my calculations, enclosed in if-else statements, are not working. JavaScript is reading `costBox`, `costShipping`, and `costTotal` as undefined. I have tried changing around the syntax, and I've gone over the code to ensure that there are no missing parentheses or brackets. I've consulted my textbook, but the code is laid out similarly there. Can you help me figure out what's wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
       var costBox;
       var costShipping;
       var costTotal;

       if (num >= 1 && num <= 5) {
        costBox == 20;
       }
       else if (num >= 6 && num <= 9) {
        costBox == 15;
       }
       else if (num == 10) {
        costBox == 10;
       }

       if (num >= 1 && num <= 3) {
        costShipping == 5;
       }
       else if (num >= 4 && num <= 7) {
        costShipping == 10;
       }
       else if (num == 8 || num == 9) {
        costShipping == 15;
       }
       else if (num == 10) {
        costShipping == 20;
       }

       costBox == costBox * num;
       costTotal == costBox + costShipping; 

       window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("pageNum").innerHTML = num;
        document.getElementById("pageBox").innerHTML = costBox.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("pageShipping").innerHTML = costShipping.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("pageTotal").innerHTML = costTotal.toFixed(2);
       }
```

Here is the code after NPE's recommendations:

```
       var num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
       var costBox;
       var costShipping;
       var costTotal;

       if (num >= 1 && num <= 5) {
        costBox = 20;
       }
       else if (num >= 6 && num <= 9) {
        costBox = 15;
       }
       else if (num == 10) {
        costBox = 10;
       }

       if (num >= 1 && num <= 3) {
        costShipping = 5;
       }
       else if (num >= 4 && num <= 7) {
        costShipping = 10;
       }
       else if (num = 8 || num = 9) {
        costShipping = 15;
       }
       else if (num = 10) {
        costShipping = 20;
       }

       costBox == costBox * num;
       costTotal == costBox + costShipping; 


       window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("pageNum").innerHTML = num;
        document.getElementById("pageBox").innerHTML = costBox.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("pageShipping").innerHTML = costShipping.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("pageTotal").innerHTML = costTotal.toFixed(2);
       }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a comparison, not an assignment:

```
    costBox == 20;
```

Change `==` to `=` (here and in all other similar places).

Also note that `Math.random()` is permitted to return exactly `0`, and your code is not handling that.

Comment: I tried that, but now, it seems like even less of the code is working. The variable `num`, the number from the random number generator, appears to read out undefined, as well as `costBox` and `costShipping` and `costTotal`.

Comment: @Michael: Are you sure you didn't change `=` to `==`? (You need to be doing the opposite.)

Comment: Yes. I changed many `==` to `=`. I tried to use `=` in assignments (such as `costBox = 20;`) and `==` otherwise (such as for `costBox == costBox * num`). I'm going to edit the original post and add the new code after your recommendations.

Comment: @Michael: You are still using `==` for assignments (e.g. in `costBox == costBox * num`). You need to fix all of those.

Comment: You were right. I was getting very confused about `=` and `==`. I had to change many of them to `=` but needed to leave some, such as `else if (num == 8 | num == 9)`, as `==` in order for it to work. Thank you.